# How to compute confidence interval of function of Gaussian Process Resgression

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process

I have some data that I have modeled as a function of two Gaussian Process Regression models $X_i(p_i)$, where $p_i$ is a parameter, so my regression models is: $y(p_1, p_2) = f(X_1, X_2) = X_1(p_1)*(1 - exp(a/X_2(p_2)) $

I know how to compute confidence intervals for $X_i(p_i)$ for a given value of parameter $p_i$, but how do I compute a confidence interval for $y(p_1, p_2)$??

Comment: You can do even better than a confidence interval for $X_1$ and $X_2$: you actually know their entire distribution! It's a Gaussian (or $t$ if you want to integrate the error term out). So you can draw samples from the posteriors on $X_{1,2}$ and then put those samples through the function you have given to get samples of $y$. Then, use a quantile function to determine the confidence interval.

Comment: @JohnMadden - might want to expand that into an answer!

Comment: Thanks @JohnMadden! If I understand you correctly I should do a Montecarlo simulation and then estimate the confidence interval based on that sample? That seems logical but maybe computational expensive, so I wonder if you meant there is some way to calculate it analitically